# How to make the columns selections in dataframe when passed few columns as list

Tags: pandas, list, join, split, tuples

I have the function contains 3 parameters:

```
def foo(df, columns, additional_col=None):
       df = df[columns + additoinal columns]
```

if additional_col parameter then only it should append it to columns else it should keep columns as column selection

Example:

```
columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
addtional_col = ["X", "Y"]
```

if additional_col is passed while calling the function foo then column selection would be
`df["A", "B", "C", "D", "X", "Y"]` elseif  additional_col is None then `df["A", "B", "C", "D"]`

tried join, map and split but couldn`t achieve the desire output. Need help on immediate basis.
Thanks

Comment: So I think you are just wanting to know how to **extend** a list ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firstly, you will need to make sure that you make a copy of the `columns` list to prevent unexpected side effects of extending the original list.
- If `additional_col` has items in the list it will equate to `True` when used in an `if-statement`.
- So if `additional_col` has items, you can extend the `columns` list using the `extend()` function.
- If it does not have items, then just use the original `columns` list.

Here is the code:

#### Code:

```
def foo(df, columns, additional_col=None):
    columns = list(columns)
    if additional_col:
        columns.extend(additional_col)
        df = df[columns]
    else:
        df = df[columns]
    
    return df
        

data = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3], "B":[4,5,6], "C":[7,8,9], "X":['a','b','c'], "Y":['d','e','f']})
    
cols = ["A","B","C"]
a = ["X","Y"]

print(foo(data, cols,a))

print("-------------------")

print(foo(data, cols))
```

#### Output:

```
   A  B  C  X  Y
0  1  4  7  a  d
1  2  5  8  b  e
2  3  6  9  c  f
-------------------
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```